# Как заменить удаленные недели на максимальные записи c рядом стоящими неделями?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть [данные](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ePZkLqqNiwvHzi3cRtMUayGU9p7g9y6/view) с выбросами.

Данные еженедельные.
После удаления выбросов количество записей уменьшится, а значит будут удалены недели.

Как заменить удаленные недели на максимальные записи рядом?

```
Q1 =  df['y'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['y'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
df[(df['y'] < Q1-1.5*IQR ) | (df['y'] > Q1+1.5*IQR)]['y']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы удалять выбросы, а после этого заполнять удаленные пропуски, проще и быстрее сразу ["срезать"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) выбросы определенными заранее границами:

```
lower_bound = ...
upper_bound = ...

df["y"] = df["y"].clip(lower=lower_bound, upper=upper_bound)
```

Comment: Я пыталась удалять до разбивки по неделям, удаляется 90 процентов записей. Смысл в том, что в течение недели "y" может быть чаще или реже в "ширину", больше или меньше в "длину". А когда итоговые выбросы после суммирования по неделям удалять - удаляется всего 4-8 выбросов. Поэтому решено было удалять выбросы после недельной разбивки. Как  границы прописывать? lower_bound = Q1-1.5*IQR , upper_bound =   Q1+1.5*IQR

Comment: @svil, два раза перечитал ваш комментарий и мало что понял. Мне незнакомы понятия "ширины" и "глубины" вектора)

Comment: Cпасибо, крутой результат получился.

Comment: Можно каким-нибудь скользящим средним заменить попробовать. Либо если выбросов в таргете много, то вообще отдельную модель по ним строить, отличную от основной. Либо добавлять столбец в данные, где будет пометка, что в этой строке есть выбросы. Вариантов много что можно сделать ещё.